# Check email to be unique php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am creating a website about music and at the bottom of my website I have a form that has only email submission. I am doing this in order to gather email from the users.

Moreover, I have created a database and in that database I have created a table called emails with only 2 columns:`id`and `email`.

I would like to make the emails that I receive unique, because now that I am testing it I can put many emails with the same name. I have tried some coding in order to achieve this but no luck so I will post only the code I have at the moment, so you can help me with what I need to add in that code in order to receive a unique email address.

P.S I will update my database from mysql to mysqli at the end of the project.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
include('../database/db.php');
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($email != "") {
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')");
echo "Thank you for Submitting. Redirecting back to Home Page";
}
?>
```

Comment: set the column `email` as unique in the database?

Comment: ...and use INSERT IGNORE, or INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
include('../database/db.php');
$email = $_POST['email'];
if($email != "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails where email='".$email."'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows >= 1){
        echo "email exist";
    }else{
        $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')");
        echo "Thank you for Submitting. Redirecting back to Home Page";
    }
}
```

replace your code with this :)

Answer (score 3):

- First.. as @RamRaider already commented you must add an unique index to the `email` column
- Second.. you must stop using `mysql_*` functions because they are deprecated. You may use `mysqli_*` functions, `MySQLi` class or `PDO`. Also, by using prepared statements, you avoid [SQL Injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
- Even if you set an unique index, you should always verify before inserting it:

  ```
  <?php

  // PDO instantiation here

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(email) AS EmailCount FROM emails WHERE email = :email');
  $stmt->execute(array('email' => $_POST['email']));
  $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($result['EmailCount'] == 0) {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (:email)');
      $stmt->execute(array('email' => $_POST['email']));
      echo 'Thank you for Submitting. Redirecting back to Home Page';
  } else {
      echo 'E-mail exists!';
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This will not go into how you need to clean your PHP. [(Helpful tips)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

As @RamRaider suggests, update the email column to be unuiqe.

Then set the result of your `mysql_query()` to be a variable which can be examined to see if there was a valid execution or not.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')");
 if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    // Something good happened and email was unuiqu
 }
else{
    // well we have encountered a problem and need to fix that or inform he user
}
```

As you can see, it will check the result you tried to execute to determine if there was a successful item added.

Comment: If your database is case sensitive don´t forget to persist all mail addresses in the same case to prevent persisting the same mail address twice in different notation.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the email before insertion like below

```
if($email != "") {
$sql = mysql_query ("select * from `emails` where email='".$email."'");
$fetch = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($fetch>0)
{
echo "email already inserted";
}
else
{
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')");
echo "Thank you for Submitting. Redirecting back to Home Page";
}}
```